# Big Picture — What sort of feed for an iOS news app?

Tags: ios, wordpress

Alright — this sort of question shows my naïveté but I am asking it nonetheless so I don't venture down the wrong rabbit hole while trying out this app.

I'm making what amounts to a news app. Imagine taking a Wordpress blog and fitting it to iOS. Now, here's my question — what sort of feed / architecture should I be using to push information from my Wordpress server to my app? I would assume RSS using AFNetworking, but that seems to cause some rough edges, and all tutorials that I see end up pushing to a web view instead of a scrollview with nice, rendered text. Plus, none of the same tutorials seem to have anything further than the initial feed (loading more than the initial 10 stories given, for example).

I've already committed a few hours to trying the RSS / AFNetworking approach, but is there a significantly better alternative that I just haven't come across. (Note that I do have access to the back-end of my Wordpress site, i.e. it isn't somebody else's)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an iOS app that connects to WordPress, I suggest you to access the website data by an API instead of feed, then you can hit the API from your app and manipulate the data as you want.

If you have access to the WordPress backend, check the [Thermal API](http://thermal-api.com/) which is a plugin that will probably solve your problem.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ this is to be added to the core of wordpress so it would seem that is the way to go I think.

By the way I am working on the same type of thing as you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most popular Wordpress API is the one that comes with Jetpack. You can find its documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

If you just want read access, then i think the easiest way to do so is by using: https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/blob/master/AlamofireJsonToObjectsTests/WordpressTest.swift

If you also want write access, then you have to implement Oauth2. For that you can select a library from: https://cocoapods.org/?q=oauth